# What causes this bad request?

Tags: python, flask

My flask application view function:

```
@app.route("/database_filter", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def database_filter():

    error = ''
    points = ''
    time_search = False
    hdop_search = False
    points_len = 0
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    c = conn.cursor()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        '''If all datetime forms are filled out and the start is not after the end, set time_search True'''

        if request.form['startdate'] and \
            request.form['starttime'] and \
            request.form['enddate'] and \
            request.form['endtime']:
            start = request.form['startdate'] + 'T' + request.form['starttime']
            end = request.form['enddate'] + 'T' + request.form['endtime']
            if datetime_object(start) > datetime_object(end):
                error = '**Start value selected must occur before End value.'
                return render_template('database_filter.html', error=error)
            else:
                time_search = True
                print 'time search: ' + str(time_search)

        if request.form['hdop_oper'] and request.form['hdop']:
            hdop_search = True
            print 'hdop and hdop_oper exist'
            hdop_oper = request.form['hdop_oper']
            hdop = float(request.form['hdop'])


        '''Prepare search statement based on forms selected'''

        if time_search == True and hdop_search == True:
            print 'Time and hdop:'
            search_string = 'SELECT * from (SELECT TSTAMP, LAT, LON, FILE, HDOP FROM POINTS WHERE TSTAMP BETWEEN "%s" and "%s") WHERE HDOP %s %.1f ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC'%(start, end, hdop_oper, hdop)
            print search_string

        if time_search == False and hdop_search == True:
            print 'Hdop only'
            search_string = 'SELECT TSTAMP, LAT, LON, FILE, HDOP FROM POINTS WHERE HDOP %s %.1f ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC'%(hdop_oper, hdop)
            print search_string

        if time_search == True and hdop_search == False:
            print 'Time only'
            search_string = 'SELECT TSTAMP, LAT, LON, FILE FROM POINTS WHERE TSTAMP BETWEEN "%s" and "%s" ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC'%(start, end)
            print search_string

        if time_search == False and hdop_search == False:
            print 'no time no hdop'
            error = 'No search criteria selected.'
            search_string = 'SELECT TSTAMP, LAT, LON, FILE FROM POINTS ORDER BY TSTAMP DESC'
            print search_string

        '''Execute SQL search and return dictionary of points'''

        cur = c.execute(search_string)

        points = [dict(TSTAMP=row[0][11:20], DATE=row[0][0:10],
            LAT=row[1],
            LON=row[2],
            FILE = row[3]) for row in cur.fetchall()]

        points_len = len(points)

        return render_template('database_filter.html', error=error, points=points, points_len=points_len)

    return render_template('database_filter.html', error=error, points=points, points_len=points_len)
```

And the html page to render it:

```
<!--Filter Search criteria form -->
<form action="database_filter" id="database_filter" method="post">
    <p id="basicExample">
        <!-- Date/time range form; requires js library at bottom -->
        <input type="test" placeholder="Start Date" class="date start" name="startdate" value="{{ request.form.startdate }}">
        <input type="test" placeholder="Start Time" class="time start" name="starttime" value="{{ request.form.starttime }}">  to  
        <input type="test" placeholder="End Date" class="date end" name="enddate" value="{{ request.form.enddate }}">
        <input type="test" placeholder="End Time" class="time end" name="endtime" value="{{ request.form.endtime }}">
    </p>

    <br>

    <strong>HDOP Filter</strong><br>
    <select name="hdop_filter">
        <option>HDOP</option>
    </select>


    <select id="hdop_oper" name="hdop_oper">
        <option>&lt;</option>
        <option>&gt;</option>
        <option>&ge;</option>
        <option>&le;</option>
        <option>&#61;</option>
        <option selected disabled value=''></option>
    </select>


        HDOP Value;
        <input type="number" id="hdop" name="hdop" min="0" max="2" step=".1">


<input class="btn-default" type="submit" value="Update Search">
<br>
<strong>*Number of points found: </strong>{{points_len}}
</form>
<br>
<br>





    <h4>{{error}}</h4>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Date =</strong> YYYY-MM-DD  <strong>Time =</strong> HH:MM:SS</p>


    {% for point in points %}
    <pre>
    <strong>Date:</strong> {{ point.DATE }} <strong>Time:</strong> {{ point.TSTAMP }}
    <strong>Latitude:</strong>  {{ point.LAT }}  <strong>Longitude:</strong> {{ point.LON }}
    <strong>Source File:</strong> {{point.FILE }}</pre>
    {% endfor %}





            <!-- datetime formatting https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time -->
            <!-- http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ -->
            <script>
                $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                    'scrollDefault': 'now',
                    'showDuration': true,
                    'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'
                });

                $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
                    'scrollDefault': 'now',
                    'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    'autoclose': true
                });
                $(document).ready(ready);

                var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
                var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
            </script>
            <!-- END Script for date time picker -->
```

Any time I select all the date time values, and no hdop values, flask returns a "Bad Request". However, if I pick just the hdop filter info and no date time, it returns the data as expected. Any clues? I see no difference in the two other than their form types.

Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Somewhere in that large view method there is an unhandled exception. Have you tried turning on debugging? `app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: Yes, it's currently on. However, it's not showing the exception, just delivering a bad request page.

Comment: Have you checked the web server error log? The packet sniffer output?

Comment: What does it say in the terminal? HAve you tried using `pdb`? SO is not for debugging your code,

Comment: I've never heard of pdb, I'll look into that. Thanks for the recommendation. I've added print statements all over the place as you can see, and in the console, the line that states " print 'hdop and hdop_oper exist' " never executes. Which leads me to believe it's an error in my logic, but I've read it over dozens of times and don't see any reason it shouldn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the method call to get the form values for hdop_oper and hdop.

The correct way to get an optional form in Flask is to use the following:

```
if request.form.get('hdop_oper') and request.form.get('hdop'):
```

Instead of:

```
if request.form['hdop_oper'] and request.form['hdop']:
```

I'd like to point out that the traceback function of Flask does not raise the 'keyerror' exception, leaving you to guess what the real problem is.

I understand SO is not for debugging your code, but I'm sure some Flask pro's out there would have caught this Flask anomaly. If nothing else, someone may find this helpful in the future.